# AdDuplex: Something is covering the ad control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 application where I have created a user control to show Pubcenter ads along with AdDuplex ads. When i fail to receive an ad from pubcenter I toggle the visibility of the two controls.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">

    <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="2ebbd26b-9e78-4fe6-9d32-2880b3246d9e" AdUnitId="177651" Name="MSAdControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Height="80" Width="480" Visibility="Visible"/>
    <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="AdDuplexAdControl" AppId="104211"  Width="480" Height="80" Visibility="Collapsed" IsTest="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Now in my MainPage.xaml, I use the ad control at the top of the page as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:AdControl Grid.Row="0"/>

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1" Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
```

But everytime an ad from adduplex loads I get a Something is covering the ad control error and on debugging I see that the culprit element is "system.windows.controls.border" and I have no clue from where that is coming from.

Here is a screenshot of the red mark which represents the covered area.

[image]

Comment: Reach out to Jeff Harmon on Twitter

Comment: I did but to no success yet! Weirdly, the red mark is on the 'ax' logo

Comment: Jeff will get back to you. He's an adduplex evangelist. Unfortunately I just started with adduplex myself so I am not much help other than pointing you toward him.

Comment: I'm not at a computer where I can test this yet, but I will research it more once I am.  In the mean-time, I included AdDuplex in my reply to you on Twitter, so they may hopefully get back to you even sooner.  They are based in Lithuania though, so it is night-time for them right now.

Comment: The adduplex people emailed me and where able to help. Thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, I only create the AdDuplex control when the PubCenter one fails, instead of messing with visibility.

Try using something similar to this code, where there is a Grid (adPanel) that stores the PubCenter ad at first, but will have AdDuplex added to it if needed.  'ad' is the PubCenter control, and you can add this code is run on page load, or just setup its ErrorOccurred event through the designer.

```
        ad.ErrorOccurred += (snd, args) =>
        {
            if (ad.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                ad.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                AdDuplex.Controls.AdControl adAd = new AdDuplex.Controls.AdControl { AppId = "104211" };
                adPanel.Children.Insert(0, adAd);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Infact if I just use only the AdDuplex control and remove the pubcenter control entirely, I still seem to get the same issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error from the UA AdDuplex control when it is the only thing on the page...